# compare schema of tables and script of stored-procedures between 2 databases

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, database-schema

**source : MS-SQL 2005**

**destination : MS-SQL 2012**

somehow I need to change developing database from one to another but unfortunately the "to database" does have had some tables and SPs already and the worse, those objects such as tables might have some columns with different name or types or even descriptions inconsistent between.

what am I supposed to do to achieve sth like, maybe easier or smarter,

- append new columns to tables which already existed (and also put col's default value and description from source)
- change types of columns consistent to source
- prevent overwriting contents of SPs already appeared in destination (but will review manually later)

So far I can figure out some statistics by the follwing scripts

- select name from sys.Tables order by name  (export to left.txt and right.txt and compare them between)
- select * from sys.all_objects where type='p' and is_ms_shipped=0 order by name (also compare them between)
- get all column names in one line per table (and compare them between), 
  e.g.

--sth like SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS, but select into only ONE line per table

```
declare @temp_table_list table(
id int identity not null,
name varchar(100) not null
)

insert @temp_table_list(name) select name from sys.tables

declare @id int
declare @name varchar(100)
declare @result as nvarchar(max) 
set @result = N''

while 1 = 1
begin

select @id = min(id)
FROM @temp_table_list
where id > isnull(@id,0)

if @id is null break

select @name = name
FROM @temp_table_list
where id = @id

declare @tbName as nvarchar(max)
declare @sql as nvarchar(max)
declare @col as nvarchar(max)

Set @tbName = @name

DECLARE T_cursor CURSOR FOR
select c.name from sys.columns c
inner join sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id
inner join sys.types tp on tp.user_type_id = c.system_type_id
where t.name =@tbName 
OPEN T_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM T_cursor into @col
set @sql = N'select '
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
set @sql = @sql+@col+','
FETCH NEXT FROM T_cursor into @col
END
set @sql =substring( @sql,0,len(@sql)) +' from '+ @tbName 
CLOSE T_cursor
DEALLOCATE T_cursor

set @result = @result + @sql + '/r/n'

end

select @result
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't free software, but it does have a trial period:

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/

As it sounds like your requirement is a one off sync, then that should do what you want.